# Transfer data between components?

Tags: angular, angular-material

There is a parent component on which the input field and the button are located.

```
<mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <input matInput placeholder="Contractor" formControlName="SPR_CONTRACTORS_ID" required>
    <button mat-button color="primary" matSuffix (click)="openDialog()">Add</button>
</mat-form-field>
```

This component is intended to add data (there are also other input fields). Data is added using this form.

```
  initializeForm() {
    if (this.data.action == 'add') {
      this.form = new FormGroup({
        LOGIN: new FormControl(null, [Validators.required]),
        PASSWORD: new FormControl(null, [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(8)]),
        FIO: new FormControl(null, [Validators.required]),
        ROLES_ID: new FormControl(null, [Validators.required]),
        EMAIL: new FormControl(null, [Validators.email]),
        PHONE: new FormControl(null, [Validators.minLength(11)]),
        SPR_CONTRACTORS_ID: new FormControl(null, [Validators.required])
      })
    }
  }
```

The button that is located next to the input field should bring up a dialog box.

```
  openDialog() {
    let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogContractorComponent, {
      height: '540px',
      width: '500px',
      data: { title: 'Contractors'}
    })
    dialogRef.afterClosed()
  }
```

In this dialog box is a table.

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="contractors" matSort matSortActive="CONTRACTOR_NAME" matSortDisableClear
    matSortDirection="asc">

    <ng-container matColumnDef="CONTRACTOR_NAME">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Contractor </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.contractor_name}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="CONTRACTOR_ID">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef></th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
            <button mat-icon-button color="primary" (click)="selectContractor(row)" matTooltip="Select"
                [mat-dialog-close]>
                <mat-icon>add</mat-icon>
            </button>
        </td>
    </ng-container>

    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
</table>
```

And on each line there is a button to choose. Clicking on it must be added to the input field in the parent component. I made the selection function.

```
  selectContractor(row: Contractor) {
    this.selectedContractors = this.contractors.find(
      el => {
        return el.contractor_id === row
      }
    )
  }
```

How now to make the data added to the input field? I can not understand. Is there a more accurate example suitable for me?

Comment: Please consult [official docs](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction). In case you need further assistance consider adding a stackblitz example of your code, along with the desired behaviour.

Comment: If your dialog is being opened by the parent component passing data back to it is simple. You need the matdialogref, from there you can grab the data and use patchvalue to add it to your controls more can be found here https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview

Comment: see my Stack Blitz  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sfm9a2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sfm9a2

```js
 
 //it is possible to do it directly after closing the dialog
 openDialog() {
    let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogContractorComponent, {
      height: '540px',
      width: '500px',
      data: { title: 'Contractors'}
    })
    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(data=>{
    this.form.get('contractor_id').patchValue(data)
    
    })
  }
```